# Change Client id to Client Name with CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

Okay, so I have a form in CakePHP that submits to a database. In this form it submits a field called `client_id` and it is stored in the database as such as well.

Then I have a view to allow me to view all of the invoices that have ever been created. To view the client responsible for the invoice, I can currently only see the id entered in the form by placing: `<?php echo $invoice['Invoice']['client_id']; ?>` in the view.

The invoices go to one database called: invoices

**The clients name is not stored in the invoices table, just the id**

The clients information is stored in one database called: clients

I want to be able to actually display out the clients real name in the invoices view rather than the client id.

I tried adding the following query to my index controller, But i'm not sure what to do after this or if this is even right.

`$this->set('clients',  $this->Invoice->query("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE id='89545'"));`

In order to keep this question short in the first place, Please request specific code by commenting. i.e. Controller code, view code, etc... Thank you in advance.

**Additional Thoughts**

If I wasn't using CakePHP I could use something like the following, So I guess I just don't know how to put this into cakephp "language".

```
<?php
 query($con, "SELECT name FROM clients WHERE id='$client_id'");

echo $row['name'];
?>
```

roughly!

**Update**

Here are my models

First one being the `Client.php`

```
<?php

class Client extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Invoice' => array(
            'className' => 'Invoice',
            'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
        )
    );
}

?>
```

Second one being the `Invoice.php`

```
<?php

class Invoice extends AppModel {
     public $belongsTo = array(
        'Client' => array(
            'className' => 'Client',
            'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
        )
    );
}

?>
```

And finally, to get my invoices from the database, I am using the following inside: `InvoicesController.php`

```
public function index() {
        $this->set('invoices', $this->Invoice->find('all'));

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you properly set up your [model associations](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html)? If so you should be able to do something like `$invoice['Client']['client_name']` assuming you didn't use `recursive = -1`.

/edit: Ok I don't mind throwing some code out, but this is a fundamental concept you'll have to try to wrap your head around. Every model that is connected to another model has to have the association set up or things will be painful.

I am assuming a `Client hasMany Invoice`. So each invoice is specific to a client, and they can have multiple invoices (ex. October 2013 vs November 2013 invoice). From the CakePHP page we see:

```
class User extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Comment' => array(
            'className' => 'Comment',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'conditions' => array('Comment.status' => '1'),
            'order' => 'Comment.created DESC',
            'limit' => '5',
            'dependent' => true
        )
    );
}
```

So using that as our template, we end up with:

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Invoice' => array(
        'className' => 'Invoice',
        'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
    )
);
```

And that goes in `Client.php`. As the inverse of `hasMany` is `belongsTo`, we have an `Invoice belongsTo Client`. Again, using the CakePHP page as the template, we end up with:

```
 public $belongsTo = array(
    'Client' => array(
        'className' => 'Client',
        'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
    )
);
```

And that goes in `Invoice.php`. Once you set up those associations, whenever you do something like `$this->Invoice->find('all');` or `$this->paginate('Invoice');`, with proper `$recursive` settings, Cake will grab the corresponding `Client` record. This allows you to do what I said before, something like `$invoice['Client']['client_name']`.

Comment: I receive this error: Notice (8): Undefined index: Client [APP/View/Invoices/index.ctp, line 22] let me post my view and controller code.

Comment: Just post your association code, `$hasMany`,`$hasOne` or `$hasAndBelongsToMany`. If those are not set up correctly then Cake will not perform the necessary `joins` behind the scenes, giving you that error.

Comment: I posted exactly what I have in the controller and view. Very new to cakephp

Comment: Yeah you're going to need to set up your model associations before you can use `$invoice['Client']['client_name']`. Take a look at the link I posted in my first answer and go through it and try to get it working. It shouldn't pose too much of a problem. If you still need help just reply, or better yet ask another question, and I'll be more than willing to help out. Just try yourself first :)

Comment: Ok I will try to get the model assocations set up.

Comment: Yeah, I'm completely lost... The documentation is not very good based on step by step and explaining the code.

Comment: See my edit. Hopefully it helps in some way, I admit I am not the greatest teacher.

Comment: I am still receiving the same error. Would you be able to share my screen? I really want to figure this out, But I don't want to be spoon fed, I want to understand when I'm done.

Comment: I won't be able to share your screen until 6:30 PM EST or later. If you can edit your original post, switch your controller/view code for your model code `Client.php` and `Invoice.php`. If you aren't seeing any `Client` data in `$invoices` it is because of the associations. If you could also paste the SQL query Cake is using to  find `Invoices` that will help as well.

Comment: Unfortunately the code looks good from where I'm sitting. Can you post the SQL query Cake is performing? I'm a bit at a loss as to why it isn't working, though. If your primary keys don't follow Cake convention may need to specify `var $primaryKey = 'primary_key';` but I wouldn't expect that to have a huge impact on things.

Comment: Found the issue, We had: `$invoice['Client']['client_name']` and in the database it is simply saved as `name` so I changed it to: `$invoice['Client']['name']` and wallah! It works. You have been an awesome awesome awesome help! I appreciate you helping me and not judging me! Thank you!

Comment: Ah! Glad to hear it worked out for you. Do not worry at all, we are all here to learn. I was in your exact shoes 8 months ago. I've come to love Cake in those 8 months, though :) Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the $actsAs = array('Containable'); in the model in order to use the 'contain' directive in your controller's find method (instead of using recursive which most likely will get unwanted data on models with many relations)